# How to implement github like markup converter and add html

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dom-events, custom-controls

I am creating the text editor and I want to implement a GitHub mark like syntax `([text|link])` and convert this to `<a heref="link">text</a>`.

I am using the below code:

```
let range = timeline.contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString();
      let info = null;
      info = range.match(/\[*(.*)\|\s*(.*)]/);
      let html =
        "<a  href=" +
        (info !== null ? info[2] : range) +
        ">" +
        (info !== null ? info[1] : range) +
        "</a>";
      innerDoc.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
```

So I have implemented this on button click but I need to achieve this in `keyDown` event for example if the user hit enters I want to get the last line and parse the link and add the anchor tag.

Basically I want to implement something like this gif:

[image: gif]

Can you please help me to achieve this functionality as soon as the user types `[text|link]` and hits <kbd>enter</kbd>?

Comment: So the code you posted is working and you just want to do it on Enter? Register an event listener for the `keydown` event, then filter by `e.code === "Enter"` and run your function.

Comment: Actually this code works if i made selction using mouse first then Call this function but now i am trying to implement on run time as user typing...so for example using the user types [google|www.google.com] and hit enter i want make the selection on the lin and then call this function..i hope i made it clear..

Comment: please refer to this [gif](https://gccontent.blob.core.windows.net/forum-uploads/file-4c07be62-8635-4d7f-aed4-82399514409e.gif)